# syntax error during VIEW creation in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jboss

I am trying to write a VIEW query in MySQL . These are the following my queries .

```
CREATE VIEW SAMPLE_TEST(server, xml) AS
  WITH ServerSettings(server, ServerSettings) AS (
    SELECT
      S.ID
    FROM SERVER S
    INNER JOIN SAMPLE_MAC DMA ON S.DOMAIN = DMA.DOMAIN
    ORDER BY S.ID
  ),
  DomainSettings(server, DomainSettings) AS (
    SELECT
      S.ID,
    FROM SERVER S
    INNER JOIN DOMAIN D ON D.ID = S.DOMAIN
    ORDER BY S.ID
  )

  SELECT SS.server,
    XMLCONCAT(
      DS.DomainSettings,
      SS.ServerSettings
    )
  FROM ServerSettings SS
  INNER JOIN DomainSettings DS ON SS.server = DS.server;
```

and when i am running on MySQL , i am getting following error message .

```
right syntax to use near 'ServerSettings(server, ServerSettings) AS (
    SELECT
      S.ID
    FROM SERVE' at line 6
```

but as per MySQL document , i can see  `CREATE VIEW AS WITH` is existing . Still i am missing any syntax error ? Any suggestion please

Comment: what's the version of MySQL you are running?

Comment: MySQL 5.7.12 . we can also compile in http://rextester.com/l/mysql_online_compiler online

Comment: support for CTE (WITH clause) is added in version 8.0. Prior versions don't support it.

Comment: So How to write these queries in  
MySQL 5.7.12  ? or shouldn't write ?

Comment: i am using `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper` will it support ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So How to write these queries in MySQL 5.7.12 ?

Either use sub-queries or create several views.

1) sub-queries

```
 CREATE VIEW SAMPLE_TEST(server, xml) AS
  SELECT SS.server,
    XMLCONCAT(
      DS.DomainSettings,
      SS.ServerSettings
    )
  FROM (
         SELECT S.ID AS SERVER
              , S.SERVERSETTINGS -- ?
           FROM SERVER S
          INNER JOIN SAMPLE_MAC DMA 
             ON S.DOMAIN = DMA.DOMAIN 
        ) SS
        INNER JOIN (SELECT S.ID AS SERVER,
                         ,  S.DOMAINSETTINGS -- ?
                      FROM SERVER S
                           INNER JOIN DOMAIN D 
                              ON D.ID = S.DOMAIN) DS 
           ON SS.server = DS.server;
```

2) Separate views

```
CREATE VIEW ServerSettings AS (
    SELECT S.ID AS SERVER
         , S.SETTINGS   -- SETTING COLUMN(S)? 
      FROM SERVER S
           INNER JOIN SAMPLE_MAC DMA 
              ON S.DOMAIN = DMA.DOMAIN;

CREATE VIEW DomainSettingsAS AS (
    SELECT S.ID AS SERVER,
         , D.DOMAINSETTINGS -- DOMAIN SETTINGS COLUMN(S) 
      FROM SERVER S
             INNER JOIN DOMAIN D 
                ON D.ID = S.DOMAIN;

SELECT SS.server,
       XMLCONCAT(
             DS.DomainSettings,
             SS.ServerSettings )
  FROM ServerSettings SS
       INNER JOIN DomainSettings DS 
          ON SS.server = DS.server;
```

Comment: `ORDER BY S.ID` is required ? or not ?

Comment: @user39320 Order final result. There is no point in using `order by` in subqueries in this case.